# Creating one element on after();

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery. Is there any other way to limit of creating elements?

here's my code..

```
if($(this).val() == "") {
   $(this).addClass('error').after('<span class="jquery_form_error_message">' + 'This field is required' + "</span>");
   validated = false;
   return false;
```

this is actually a validation .. you can't skip unless you field out every field data. 
my problem is . when I click the submit . button.. it create a multiple span class on on the top of div.. which it's quite a mess.

Comment: Don't do validation yourself, because you're reinventing the wheel and you're not at the right level of skill to do it properly. Try jquery Validation. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the element exists:

```
if ($(this).next('.jquery_form_error_message').length > 0) {
  // Exists
} else {
  // Doesn't exist
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 function test() {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                $(this).addClass('error').after($(this).next('span.jquery_form_error_message').length === 1 ? ('<span class="jquery_form_error_message">' + 'This field is required' + "</span>") : '');
                validated = false;
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $(this).removeClass('error').next('span.jquery_form_error_message').hide();
                validated = true;
                return true;
            }
        }
```